# How to Sort or Filter by Group By Total - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, grouping, cewp

I have a long list of companies (3,500+) in a classic SharePoint list. I am trying to identify when there is a duplicate company. Right now I am grouping the Company Name field and scanning through the long list for any groups of more than 1, which is tedious. Is there a way to Sort or Filter to groups of more than 1, so that the duplicates are easier to find?

I've seen this asked a few times but all of the answers are old and don't work with SharePoint designer anymore (at least as the steps are written)

Comment: What type of column is Company Name ?

Comment: The Company Name is a single line text column (the title field). As an alternative, we could group on the company's ID # (right now this is a text column as well but could be switched to number if that helps). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you want to do can be achieved in SharePoint online. But it would be very easy to export the list to Excel and create a quick pivot table. Pull company name in the Row panel of the pivot table and again into the Values panel. Then sort by value.

Comment: Thank you - was really hoping to do this in SharePoint but appreciate the response

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for the issue, you could export the list to the excel and find the duplicate items in the excel.

For more detailed information, you could refer to the articles below.

[Identifying Duplicate Values in an Excel List.](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/identifying-duplicate-values-in-an-excel-list)

[Find Duplicates.](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html)

Comment: Thank you - was really hoping to do this in SharePoint but appreciate the response